# Neural network for text generation from examples

Tags: neural-networks

I am a student and am have been looking into machine learning and neural networks during the past year. I have basic understanding and some experience with simple neural networks.

My question is, suppose I want to train a network with a set of short phrases and I would like the network to generate output phrases based on the examples I gave it. How would one go about this? Do you have any pointers as to what I should look into to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Recurrent Neural Networks.

You could start by having a look at some papers, e.g. http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~ilya/pubs/2011/LANG-RNN.pdf
from the University of Toronto.

A more practical description can be found here:
http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/
I think this is a relatively clear example.

I hope this helps!